# How to start mailcatcher when booting vagrant box

Tags: vagrant, mailcatcher

I need to start the mailcatcher as the `vagrant up` is done.

I tried setting provision for the vagrant machine

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: 'mailcatcher --ip=0.0.0.0'
```

But it says `unidentified command mailcatcher`

Comment: how is mail catcher installed?  My guess is that it isn't in your path, so just locate it and call it via it's full path  and you should be ok.

Comment: i did, `gem install mailcatcher`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MailCatcher has to be started via `/usr/bin/env mailcatcher`so

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: '/usr/bin/env mailcatcher --ip=0.0.0.0'
```

should work.

Comment: Thanks for answering.. :) I hadn't found a solution to this till now. I am kind of in the middle of something. But i will try this out and get back soon Thanks again..

Comment: this isn't working for me. it says `no such file or directory`

Comment: @UtkarshVishnoi it's been really long since i used mailcatcher and cagrant box too. But i think you should have mailcatcher installed in your system.

Comment: Yeah i got it installed

Comment: But i want it to be autostarted on `vagrant up`

Comment: Line `--ip=0.0.0.0` saved my day

Comment: I had to reload Vagrant with the --provision flag. i.e.  vagrant reload --provision