# Auto start mailcatcher with vagrant homestead?

Tags: ruby, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-provision, mailcatcher

I installed Vagrant and Homestead on my windows system.
Ruby was installed using `rbenv` and installed `Mailcatcher`. I wanted to autostart mailcatcher with homestead whenever I try to `vagrant up` the vm.

I have also provisioned vagrant with this script as shown in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28216410/how-to-start-mailcatcher-when-booting-vagrant-box) but no luck.

`config.vm.provision "shell", inline: '/usr/bin/env mailcatcher --ip=192.168.10.10'`

It gives me error that `no such file or directory`.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: look https://github.com/puphpet/puphpet/issues/897#issuecomment-49621604

Comment: @FrédéricHenri I do not have puPHPet installed. Should i install it.

Comment: no you can just replace you inline by `'/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/default/catchmail -f email@example.com'` and run `mailcatcher --http-ip=0.0.0.0` when you're in the VM

Comment: @FrédéricHenri but I installed using rbenv not rvm. I couldn't find the path to the executable